# getting error of "got 3 arguments expected 5" while using react-native-zoom-bridge

Tags: react-native, zoom-sdk

While using react-native-zoom-bridge getting the error of "got 3 arguments expected 5" in the android simulator. Any idea?

Code:

```js
import {View, Text, Alert} from 'react-native';
import ZoomBridge from 'react-native-zoom-bridge';

const zoomMeeting() => {
  const [isInitialized, setIsInitialized] = useState(false);
  const zoomInit = async () => {
    try {
      const initializeResult = await ZoomBridge.initialize({
        clientKey: CLIENT_KEY,
        clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
      });
      setIsInitialized(true);
      console.log({ initializeResult });
    } catch (e) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Could not execute initialize');
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    zoomInit();
  }, []);

  
  return (
    <View><Text>Hello</Text></View>
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add some code how you are invoking the component ?

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: can you please let me know the version of `react-native-zoom-bridge` ?

Comment: "react-native-zoom-bridge": "^1.0.18"

Comment: This is the line in the source code of `1.0.18` version  ` zoomSDK.initialize(reactContext.getCurrentActivity(), appKey, appSecret, webDomain, RNZoomBridgeModule.this);
`

Comment: It have 5 arguments, so may be this thing causing the issue

Comment: What is the file path?

Comment: https://github.com/chaimPaneth/react-native-zoom-bridge/blob/1.0.18/android/src/main/java/com/appgoalz/reactnative/RNZoomBridgeModule.java

Comment: You need to add domain and Promise parameter

Comment: I have tried passing the domain also still not working. zoomSDK.initialize does not take promise so not passing promise won't be an issue other two parameters are class instance and current activity that gets created inside the method itself.

Comment: config.zoom.domain getting any domain from zoom config ?

Comment: it will pick by default domain "zoom.us".

Comment: you can try this library `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-zoom-us` this is well maintained, the one you are using is not reliable :(

Comment: I have tried react-native-zoom-us there also facing an initialization issue (zoomUs.initialize never returns value back) :D. I think, for now, I can try other libraries including zoom us. thanks.